# Linux GUI Regular Expression File Renamer (with substitution)

Tags: linux, regex, rename, filenames, batch-rename

I have folder with several hundred files named like this:

010203.txt

I want to rearrange the file names so that last two digits are moved to the front like this:

030102.txt

I want to avoid writing a script.

Instead, I'm looking for a "linux gui regular expression file renamer" that can recursively evaluate all files in a folder (and its sub-folders).

I want the ability to specify a regular expression for matching a file:

(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(.*)

And I want the ability to perform regular expression substitution to rename the file:

$3$1$2$4

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize this is not exactly a "GUI", but you didn't say anything *why* that is a requirement, and there are *already-written* command-line tools that do this; e.g. `perl-rename`:

```
find ~/dir -type f -exec prename -n 's/^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(.*)$/$3$1$2$4/' {} +
```

(`-n` turns on "test" mode. When you're satisfied with the output, run again with `-v` or no options instead.)

Comment: This program isn't always named the same; in the Ubuntu repositories, it is simply called `rename`. Also, it can be used on every `*.txt` in a directory directly with `prename 's/search/replace/' *.txt`, though of course this won't give the recursiveness of `find`.

Comment: I marked this as the answer, even though it is not a GUI. I like how you even covered my recursive requirement (that I kind of just threw in there to make it tough). Also check out the answer I posted regarding thunar.

Comment: How do you get it to output anything during testing? When I run the command you suggested it just immediately returns me to a command prompt.

Comment: This worked: find -type f -exec prename -n 's/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(.*)/$3$1$2$4/' {} +

Answer (score 2):

Some good GUI tools for renaming files are

- [KRename](http://www.krename.net/) for KDE desktop environment (I personally prefer this one because I'm a KDE user);
- [GPRename](http://gprename.sourceforge.net/) and [pyRenamer](http://www.infinicode.org/code/pyrenamer/) for Gnome.

Comment: Although these tools allow you to match by regular expression, I don't believe any of them support substitution like Thunar does.

Answer (score 2):

XFCE's [Thunar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunar) file manager have nice mass renamer feature.

Just select more than one file and hit `F2` to show Rename Multiple Files dialog.
From the drop down menu select `Search & Replace` option, check `[x] Regular Expression` checkbox and type `Search` and `Replace` criteria.

For example I've got several files from DVB-T grabber named

```
20190813 Okno do New Yorku.avi
20190814 Okno do Rima.avi
20190815 Okno do Bankoku.avi
20190820 Okno do Hamburgu.avi
```

Using search `([0-9]+) (.*)` and replace `DOC \2 \1` the transformation creates

```
DOC Okno do New Yorku 20190813.avi
DOC Okno do Rima 20190814.avi
DOC Okno do Bankoku 20190815.avi
DOC Okno do Hamburgu 20190820.avi
```

which is very cool.

The mass renamer also have live preview so you can see the matched lines and their transformation next to source filenames which is good for debugging the regexp. The unmatched filenames are not changed.

Comment: Thunars bulk renamer can be called from outside of Thunar, on the command line or from another file manager that is configurable. The syntax is `thunar -B file ...` or `thunar --bulk-rename file ...`. For instance in my `spacefm` I have configured a menu item for executing `thunar --bulk-rename %F`

Answer (score 2):

A combination of **renameutils** and your **favorite regex editor** (gedit, sublime, atom) might be the easiest way to go.

1. Install rename utils:

```
sudo apt install renameutils
```

or

```
sudo pacman -Syu renameutils
```

2. Run `qmv` with your favorite editor:

   2.1 Sublime:

   ```
   qmv -f do -e "subl -w" ./PATH/TO/FILES
   ```

   2.2 Atom:

   ```
   qmv -f do -e "atom -w" ./PATH/TO/FILES
   ```

   2.3 Gedit:

   ```
   qmv -f do -e "gedit" ./PATH/TO/FILES
   ```
3. Use the editor full regex capabilities (including multiselection / and `Ctrl+D`) to create the list of new names.
4. Save & Close

Comment: Annoying that it seems so roundabout for something all the other renamers claim to be able to do, but this was the only method that worked right for me.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the suggestions, but I found an easier way, using a graphical user interface.

In Ubuntu, install thunar:

```
sudo apt-get install thunar
```

Then all you have to do is navigate to a folder (with thunar) and hit ctrl-a to select all files in that folder.

After this, right-click on one of the files (you've highlighted), and select "rename" from the context menu. Then, [this dialog](http://neartalk.com/ss/2013-05-09_16:23:16.png) pops up, allowing you to do regular expression substitution for renaming.

This doesn't meet the recursive requirement I mentioned, but for changing the names of all files within a single folder, its a lot simpler than the command line, but actually, I do appreciate both methods.

Comment: The only drawback to this solution is that Thunar is a full file manager rather than a simple renamer, and the chances are that by installing it you have now two file managers on your system (Thunar and the one provided by your distro, I suppose Nautilus or Dolphin); I have to be honest, it doesn't cause any problem, it's just redundant, and if you are happy with it then everyone's fine :)

Comment: Well, the only time I'd use it is for this use-case (nautilus otherwise). It's worth the extra space that it redundantly takes up for this feature alone.

Comment: Well, the nice part of Linux is to tailor your system to your needs, so if you like it, it's your best solution.